# How to find a byte array inside another byte array

Tags: c++, c

I cannot use strstr, memchr because array can contains any number of \0 chars, is there are any efficient ways to do that? I have to find all positions (indexes) or pointers.

Comment: What did you try? There are some obvious solutions. Why don't they fit you?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are looking for here. Every index into a byte array is the start of a set of sub-arrays, varying in length from 1 to (outer array length) - index.

Comment: Why you can't use `memchr`? There you give size of byte array so `\0` bytes isn't any problem.

Comment: Oh, I think I've just understood. You want to find the offset of a particular pattern of data bytes within a larger array?

Comment: For C, if you're on a GNU system, try [`memmem`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memmem).

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you want to do in more detail. I personally don't understand at all what you are looking for.

Comment: Oh ... writing multi-language source files is **hard work**. I suggest you stick to one of `C` or `C++` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Piece of cake in C++:

```
#include <string>

const std::string needle = get_byte_sequence();
const std::string haystack = get_data();


std::size_t pos = haystack.find(needle);

// found if pos != std::string::npos
```

Another option is to use a generic algorithm:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::string::const_iterator it = std::search(data.begin(), data.end(), needle.begin(), needle.end());

if (it != data.end())
{
  // needle found at position std::distance(data.begin(), it);
}
else
{
  // needle not found
}
```

Bear in mind that C++ `string` objects can contain arbitrary data. To create a string from a byte buffer, pass its size to the constructor:

```
char buf[200];   // fill with your data; possibly full of zeros!

std::string s(buf, 200); // no problem
```

Comment: I'd vote against the find, because it's not of the string nature it seems.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: You think in such three-dimensional terms :-) Think of "string" as "string of bytes"; problem solved. Also, always think of "char" as "byte"; "char" is arguably the most inappropriately named data type...

Comment: I can think of char as byte, but I can't help thinking of char* as 0-terminated string ;-) But well, it all comes down to 3d terms - I used the word "nature" :) (and I used the words "vote against", though I didn't mean downvoting half of your answer:))

Comment: +1, except that `char buf[200];` is not full of zeroes (add initializer please).

Comment: @avakar: Sorry, misunderstanding. I mean: "This is your data, possibly this is full of zeros."

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: Luckily there's no `char*` in my code :-) I'd never think of char *arrays* as strings, for that matter.

Comment: In the string code above, there's no char either, actually :) And yes, char array doesn't trigger the same associations as pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you should look at `std::search`? (there is also `memem`, but I don't think it's extremely portable).

Answer (score 0):

If you expect to encounter null-characters, use the standard function memcmp(const void *, const void *, size_t).

Answer (score 0):

Works normally for me

```
bool BinScanner::FindSequence(const unsigned char * pSeq, unsigned long ulSeqSize)
{
    const unsigned char* pFindRes = std::search(pCurr, pEnd, pSeq, pSeq+ulSeqSize);
    if (pFindRes != pEnd)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```